# How to use custom resuable components as input fields in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, react-props, react-forms

I have a situation here where I have created a reusable component which is responsible for creating input fields and label. I want to use this component throughout to build a complete form having a single row with two columns (with this custom input field)

I use the following code

```
Form.jsx
    <GridRow>
      <InputField type="text"label="First Name"/>
       <InputField type="text"label="Last Name" />
    </GridRow>

GridRow.jsx
    
    render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Container>
                        <Row>
                            <Col sm={6}>  
                            {this.props.children}
                            </Col>
                            <Col sm={6}>
                            {this.props.children}
                           </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Container>
                </div>
            );

Inputfield.jsx
    const InputField = ({label, type}) => (
        <div>
          {label}
            <input
                type={type}     
                style={{ padding: "4px", border: "none", borderBottom: "1px solid #ccc", width: "90%"}}
            />
        </div>
    );
```

Here Form.jsx is using GridRow.jsx as component which has a child component inputfield.jsx
I want the two columns to be different in the same row.

***I'm getting the below output***

[image]

*Following is the desired output. How can i get this output*

[image]

As in the image the first row is

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this:

`form.jsx`:

```
<Row>
<Col><input /></Col>
<Col><input /></Col>
</Row>
```

`grdiRow.jsx`:

```
<Container>
{this.props.child}
</Container>
```